# robot_localization : no filtered odometry with visual odometry

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There is no filtered odometry from robot_localization when I put visual odometry as an input. Interesting thing is that robot_localization successfully produces a filtered odometry when I put wheel odometry instead of visual odometry. Both visual odometry and wheel odometry uses same ros message (i.e. nav_msgs/Odometry).  The launch file is follows.

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">

  <param name="frequency" value="20"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>

  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="map"/> 

  
  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="/visual_odometer/odometry"/>  

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, false,
                                  false, false, true,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>
  
  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

[Example of wheel odometry]
[image: image description]

[Example of visual odometry]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218741/robot_localization-:-no-filtered-odometry-with-visual-odometry/) by [Soonhac](https://answers.ros.org/users/225/soonhac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-10-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-10-07**:
Can you please post a sample message from each input?

**Comment by [Soonhac](https://answers.ros.org/users/225/soonhac/) on 2015-10-07**:
Hi Tom, I post sample messages above.

**Comment by [theDrGray](https://answers.ros.org/users/24247/thedrgray/) on 2015-10-15**:
Having the same issue with the output from rtabmap. Did you find a solution?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-10-16**:
Do the `frame_id`s in `rtabmap` start with forward slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the messages, I think you need to ditch the forward slashes in the visual odometry `frame_id`s. Also, make sure you're providing transforms from those `frame_id`s to your robot's frames. Also also, I would recommend fusing the linear velocities rather than the absolute positions, though you can fuse the orientations from the VO as is.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0